# AngularJS. I need compact way to merge custom scope with array of objects OR with single object

Tags: arrays, angularjs

In my application I need to upload files and I try to implement the feature, that allow to add new files to files array instead of override it.

This is how I do it:

```
if (files) {
    angular.forEach(files, function(file) {
        $scope.files.push(file);
    });
}
```

where files can be an array of `File` object or just single file.

Early I tried to push files to the scope as `$scope.files.push(files)`, but as result I got array of nested arrays and can't processed it via `ng-repeat`.

I also tried `$scope.files.concat(files)`, but as result I got empty array;

I also tried `angular.extend($scope.files, files)`, but I got weird result:
when I add single file, it not pushed to the $scope.files but just replace `$scope.files` first element with itself. Same result if `files` contains more than one elements.

**The question:** does it exists more compact (and maybe faster) way to merge custom scope with array of objects or just one object?

**Second question:** why when I tried to `angular.extend($scope.files, files)`, it not merged two arrays into one array, that contains elements of both, but just replace destination array with source?

Comment: `$scope.files = $scope.files.concat(files)`  (unlike push, `concat` doesn't modify the array it's called on; it returns the concatenated arrays instead.)

Comment: @DanielBeck thanks! it works!

Comment: No sweat.  Irritating inconsistency in javascript, I get caught by it myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript's Array concat function returns a new array comprised of the arrays passed in. So you need to assign the result back to your scope variable:

```
if (files) {
  $scope.files = $scope.files.concat(files);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if `files` is an array or object, then either concat or push:

```
//null check and object check
if (files && typeof files === "object") {
    if (files.length) {
        $scope.files = $scope.files.concat(files); //array merge
    } else {
        $scope.files.push(files); //single obj
    }
}
```